# Bootstrap Dropdown Menu won't work with scripts and links in correct order

Tags: jquery, angularjs, css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

**UPDATE:** To avoid confusion I forked the Plunker, and removed the other  dropdown menu. To clarify the Dropdown menu I'm having problems with is the one with the 3 bars when you resize the screen.

I'm having trouble with a bootstrap dropdown menu button with angularjs scripts, and all other scripts, and links placed in the correct order.  Here's my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wPGO01a9luGA7QyfzSAL?p=preview)

> I've been researching the problem, and so far I've tried all the
>   solutions on StackOverflow such as:

**Arranging the scripts and links in the correct order:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.2/angular-animate.min.js"></script>      
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**To forcing the dropdown toggle with JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
});
```

So far I still can't make the dropdown work here's my **HTML**:

```
 <!--Navigation Bar Relative --> 
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <!--Logo!-->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">THE LOGO</a>

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="mainNavBar">

                <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

            </div>


            <!--Menu Items!-->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Timeline</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>




                </ul>

                <!--Right-Align Menu Items!-->

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                </ul> 

            </div>

        </div>


    </nav>

<div ng-controller="">

</div>
```

Im a complete newbie at Bootstrap and AngularJS, so please explain what I'm doing wrong and help me get go in the right direction. Thank You!

http://plnkr.co/edit/wPGO01a9luGA7QyfzSAL?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed the `#` of id in data-target

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed the # at the the data toggle. Thanks for your help! I appreciate it.

Comment: It happens - took me awhile to find it :)